# Table of contents for appendix only (scrartcl)

Tags: koma-script, minitoc, appendix

using the `minitoc` package in `scrartcl` I would like to create a table of contents for the Appendix and its contents only. My code runs but I fail in creating a table of contents in the Appendix for the contents of the Appendix only. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totoc}
\usepackage{minitoc}


\begin{document}

\dosecttoc 
\tableofcontents

\section{Hello}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\secttoc
\dosecttoc 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no subsections in appendix. If I add subsections, I get the ToC in appendix:

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totoc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dosecttoc 
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\secttoc
\dosecttoc
\subsection{Foo}% <- added
\subsection{Bar}% <- added
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

But it is not recommended to use package `minito` together with a KOMA-Script class.

[image]

Suggestion with only »Appendix« in the main ToC:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totoc}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  owner=\jobname,
  listname={\contentsname},
  setup=leveldown
]{atoc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\useatocs}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ext@toc}{atoc}%
  \scr@ifundefinedorrelax{hypersetup}{}{% maybe you use hyperref and bookmarks
    \hypersetup{bookmarkstype=atoc}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\useatocs
\listofatocs
\subsection{Foo}
\subsection{Barg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Suggestion with a complete main ToC:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totoc}
\usepackage{scrwfile}
\TOCclone[{\contentsname}]{toc}{atoc}
\setuptoc{atoc}{leveldown}
\addtocontents{atoc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=-2}

\newcommand*{\useatoc}{%
  \addtocontents{atoc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=\subsubsectiontocdepth}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\useatoc
\listofatoc
\subsection{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, here comes the solution. Instead of `minitoc` use `titletoc` and things work out:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcommand\DoToC{%
  \startcontents
  \printcontents{}{2}{\textbf{Contents}\vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt}
  \vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt
}


\begin{document}


\section{Hello}

\newpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\DoToC

\subsection{goodnight}

\subsection{goodmourning}


\end{document}
```

It's important to place:

```
%toc for appendix only: 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand\DoToC{%
  \startcontents
  \printcontents{}{2}{\textbf{Contents}\vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt}
  \vskip3pt\hrule\vskip5pt
}
```

Right after `{scrartcl}` otherwise the table of content will contain missplaced `toc`s